# Shortcut to compare if statements

Tags: javascript

```
if (Progress.bar.status == 'finished' || Progress.bar.status == 'uploading'){
  //code here
}
```

How do I shorten this? I'd like to write it without having to repeat `Progress.bar.status` twice.

Something along the lines of:

```
Progress.bar.status == ('finished' or 'uploading').
```

Comment: `Progress.bar.status ? ('finished' || 'uploading'): 'something else'`

Comment: What are the other possible values?

Comment: @SwarajGiri, this does not work, because any non empty string returns true and that forces `'finished '` to return. but the requirement of `// code here` is not (can not be) implemented.

Comment: you are right. my bad

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I like lookup tables:

```
if ({finished:1, uploading:1}[Progress.bar.status]){
  //code here
}
```

this uses an object to code two or more options, and even side-steps quoting every choice. its also very fast since the object can be cached and there is no comparison logic or methods to invoke, just fast property access driving the flow...

do note that in some cases, you might want to use `Object.create(null)` and then merge/extend that blank object with your options, if you absolutely must avoid false-positives for "hasOwnProperty", "valueOf", "toString", "toLocaleString", "constructor", and a few double-underscore extensions. it's not often an issue, but it is something to keep in mind. if you can live without feeding your `if` those keywords, or building a cached collection of choices from Object.create(), it's a fast and simple way to code "one of the above" flows.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about it.

Comment: Why do you add _1_ in **{finished:1, uploading:1}**?

Comment: `1` is a value which will satisfy the `if(` when the key matches, and is quick to type. any thruthy value will do, but for many progs, `1` means yes and `0` means no...

Comment: I feel a better word would be enumerations

Comment: @vihan1086: enumerations typically convert to different numbers, the code above just needs to convert to booleans. however, lookup tables can also mimic enums: `TRANS={opaque:1, faded:0.8, ghost: 0.5, clear:0}; elm.style.opacity=TRANS.faded;` lookups can even replace 1:1 `switch` operations with a potentially recyclable choice pool (named var instead of anon obj) and typically faster execution: `elm.style.color={r:'red', g:'#040', b:'blue'}[item.colorCode];`

Comment: I like it. Readable and terse.

Answer (score 4):

Make with the wanted strings an array, apply a search for the index of the array. The result is -1 for not found and 0 ... n for a found string. to make this short and while we need only the 0 ... n result, apply a bitwise not to the result (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT)
:

```
value  ~value   boolean
 -1  =>   0  =>  false
  0  =>  -1  =>  true
  1  =>  -2  =>  true
  2  =>  -3  =>  true
  and so on
```

In code all together it looks like this:

```
if (~['finished', 'uploading'].indexOf(Progress.bar.status)) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: can you explain it as well

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest working with enumerations then a `switch()` statement:

```
var Status = {
    Finished: 'finished', 
    Uploading: 'uploading'
};

switch (Progress.bar.status) {
    case Status.Finished:
    case Status.Uploading:
      //code here
      break;
}
```

More code initially, but more flexible and readable.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that extending native object is a taboo, but:

```
String.prototype.eqOr = function(){
  var i;
  var str = this.toString();
  for(i=0; i< arguments.length; i++){
    if(arguments[i] === str){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

if(Progress.bar.status.eqOr('finished', 'uploading')){
   //code here
}
```

v2.0, thanks Ja͢ck

```
String.prototype.eqOr = function(){
   return [].indexOf.call(arguments, this.toString()) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: `return [].indexOf.call(arguments, this) !== -1;` :)

Comment: or bake a take-away: `isOk=[].indexOf.bind(['finished', 'uploading']);`